# Prevent ICS From Mounting USB Storage

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, charging, motorola-droid-razr, usb-mass-storage

I have a Motorola Droid Razr Maxx running Android 4.0.4. I'd like to prevent ICS from mounting USB storage every time I plug it into a USB host. I just want it to charge by default. I am very dissatisfied that they took away this option in the upgrade from Gingerbread to ICS.

I am willing to do stuff in the terminal that requires root privilege to prevent this from happening, but I would be happier if there is an app for it. I want my phone to **Charge Only** when I plug it into a USB host.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable USB Debugging Mode, the phone will connect to your computer and charge as usual, but you will not get any auto-mounting for the phone storage.

### Enable USB Debugging in Android 4.0

1. Click your device home button;
2. Tap "Settings";
3. Scroll your way to "Developer options" and tap it;
4. Check "USB debugging".

### Enable USB Debugging in Android 2.3

1. Click your device home button;
2. Tap on "Settings";
3. Tap on "Applications";
4. Scroll your way to "Development" and tap it;
5. Check "USB debugging".

<sup>This method works for me to charge my phone without mounting the storage.</sup>

Comment: This method does not work for me. I tried toggling USB Debugging on/off and it does not make a difference. When I plug my handset into any device, whether it's an Android tablet, a Windows PC or a Linux PC, it connects for USB Mass Storage mode. That said, I am not going to downvote your answer, because it may be a handset-specific thing. But I can't accept your answer as the correct answer because it simply doesn't work.

Comment: FWIW... This works for me. I still get the notification of new hardware, but no storage devices are mounted.

Comment: @w3d which handset are you using? Maybe this problem is specific to my phone if you're using a Razr Maxx on ICS...

Comment: @allquixotic: I'm using a reasonably generic 7" tablet - DGM T-703 with Android 4.0.3

Comment: Interesting. The only way I can plug anything into the USB of my phone without having it try to mount mass storage is to plug it into a "dumb" charging port, like the USB wall wart (120VAC to USB adapter) or a portable USB battery pack. Anything with "logic", like a computer or tablet, *does* connect to USB Debugging correctly, but it also tries to mount mass storage. **Simultaneously**. And both of them work. :/ That would be fine if I *wanted* that behavior, but it prevents me from accessing files on the handset's MicroSD card from within the phone itself.