# Android 4 USB charge only

Tags: security, 4.1-jelly-bean, usb-connection-mode

When I connect my Android 4 phone (Galaxy Nexus) to a computer using USB, the storage of the phone is automatically mounted on the computer. How can I connect my phone using USB for charging only? In Android 2.x I had to explicitely choose "USB storage", in Android 4 there is only the choice between MTP and PTP? ):

Comment: It should charge it automatically when it's plugged in. Are you using a USB cable that came with the phone?

Comment: the problem is not that it wouldn't charge, but that it does not *only* charge, but also the internal storage is mounted on the computer.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what's suppose to happen. You can umount the devices fs and than leave it to charge without having access to it's storage.

Comment: Actually on my HTC Desire with Android 2.3 that was different, I could choose on the phone whether to mount the storage or not. Nice thing if you attach your phone on a foreign computer...

Comment: Aha, now I understand why you want that feature. Well, this is a feature of Android 2.3. Here is a person with the same question, check it out: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27632/prevent-ics-from-mounting-usb-storage

Comment: Thanks, but enabling USB debugging is even worse from a security perspective. This new behaviour really sucks.

Comment: No, no. I didn't mean enable USB debugging, I know that doesn't work. It doesn't work on my ICS phone, I thought it wouldn't work for you either. I meant follow this question for answers, it's similar to yours. And I cannot answer it right now. I'm trying what you want to achieve with some other ICS phones, if I stumble upon something I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

When your phone is plugged into a computer there should be a USB symbol in the notifications bar. Tapping the notification associated with this should allow you to switch between MTP/PTP (whichever you have selected in settings) and "just charge".

EDIT: apologies, it looks as though this is an HTC-specific thing, and not general. I'm new here - should I leave this answer with this edit, or delete the answer?

Comment: My phone (Nexus S, 4.1.2) doesn't have this. Saying what phone/version of Android this applies to would add to your answer.

Comment: Apologies - it looks as though this is an HTC-specific thing.

Comment: Unsure, personally I'd leave it, there's a lot of HTC phones out there this could be useful for.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HTC desire X.  What I do is to put a password on my phone and just plug it in without unlocking the screen, which lets the phone charge without giving someone on the computer the ability to open your files.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking as long as you leave the data lines open the behavior depends on the phone *and* the computer you plug it into. Your best option would be hardware-only to make sure that the computer doesn't get to see any of the data.

A recently funded Kickstarter project named LockedUSB aims to provide exactly that, also in light of potentially malicious "charging stations" in public places. I'm not linking it since that may be considered spam and that's certainly not the intent behind this answer. A web search can lead the way to them.

From their description:

> LockedUSB is an small adapter that allows secure charging of your
>   personal devices. It physically disconnects the data lines, while
>   keeping intruders away from your personal information.

With this kind of solution you will also avoid bad surprises when you forget to switch something off in software on the phone and thereby involuntarily expose your device. Aside from that it's a generic solution that will work without software support on either side and gives you the peace of mind you seem to be looking for when charging your device in other peoples' computers.

Disclosure: I am one of the funders of the above mentioned project on Kickstarter.