# How do I prevent usb mount while the the mobile is OFF

Tags: security, usb, power-on, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I know that [this topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104096/security-how-to-prevent-usb-mounting-of-mobile-device) helps prevent USB mount. But there is such thing that while the android mobile is off, volume button + the power button starts the boot, and the android can be still mounted while it is off. How do i prevent this?

Comment: You can encrypt your device and protect it with a password. In such a case the access from within the recovery is useless.

Answer (score 0):

volume button + the power button boots the phone either to fastboot mode or recovery mode. One way to do it is to flash a recovery that does not support USB mounting. However, the thief may still flash a new recovery to access your files. At least it would be way more complicated.
I'm afraid there is no absolute way to prevent USB mount.